# Modernizr class assignment

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

I'm new to Modernizr. This may seem like an incredibly OCD question, but I'm curious as to why Modernizr adds a preceding space when it assigns a class to my page's `html` tag when it is the only class assigned?

For instance when I inspect my page in a desktop context, my page's `html` tag looks like so:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-AU" style="" class=" no-touchevents">
```

instead of:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-AU" style="" class="no-touchevents">
```

Is there a rationale as to why Modernizr adds classes in this manner?

Comment: Haha "incredibly OCD of me" disclaimer made me laugh

Comment: Hah. Glad you found it amusing—the neutral space just makes my eyes twitch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the source code for adding classes in modernizer: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/e2c27dcd32d6185846ce3c6c83d7634cfa402d19/src/setClasses.js

Looks like it's just because they're doing a `+=` on the className and are including a space in case the element already has some classes assigned.

Comment: I see. Thank you for this. I know that there won't be other classes assigned in any circumstance. So I will modify this. Although, perhaps I shouldn't mess with a good thing.